# Outlook Zoom VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to zoom the current email to 130%.

According to [this forum thread](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/anyone-have-sample-macro-outlook-2007-setting-zoom-t3785765.html) an Outlook MVP said it was not possible. That the best I could do is pop-up the zoom dialog:

```
Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ZoomDialog")
```

But that was in 2009 with outlook 2007.

Does anyone know if it's possible in Outlook 2013? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do that with an active inspector, you can use the following:

```
 set Document = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
 Document.Windows.Item(1).View.Zoom.Percentage = 130
```

If you need to work with the preview pane, you can do that using the [SafeExplorer](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeExplorer.htm) object in [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author):

```
 set sExplorer = CreateObject("Redemption.SafeExplorer")
 sExplorer.Item = Application.ActiveExplorer
 set Document = sExplorer.ReadingPane.WordEditor
 Document.Windows.Item(1).View.Zoom.Percentage = 130
```